# Open up SSIS Package as an XML or Raw File

Tags: ssis

I want to open a ".dtsx" file as a raw file or an xml file (doesn't matter which). Is this possible in SSIS? Not from what I can tell, but I wanted to see if someone else has run into this before.

**Edit #1:**

My ultimate goal is not to view the xml, but to import the xml in all the packages as text data and search the xml that way. I have about 200-300 packages to search.

Comment: "Not from what I can tell"... on what do you base this?   A .dtsx file is plain text.   What did you try?   https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/288463/import-TEXT-file-into-varcharmax\

Comment: If all of your packages are in the same place you can install a program called text crawler and have it search all of the dtsx files for whatever it is that you happen to be looking for. I use that all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To view the XML of your package right click the package and select View Code from within SSDT.  This will open the XML for it.

Comment: Also, any text editor, e.g. Notepad++, will do, too. Careful, though. A stray keystroke can break a package.

Comment: I understand that I can do that, but what I'm looking to do is take about 200-300 packages, search all of them to see if a list of table names have been used by checking all 200.

I'm not interested in looking at the xml in note pad ++, I'm hoping to import the ssis packages as raw text and search that way.

Edited original question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I would take copies of all the packages you want to search and put them in their own folder. Create a Foreach File Loop container, point it to your folder, and give it `*.dtsx` as the file wildcard. Make sure you set a variable to capture the fully qualified path to the file.

Inside the Foreach Loop, use your path variable as the connection string to a Flat File Connection. Configure the Flat File Connection with `Ragged Right` as the Format and with `Tab` as the row delimiter. You should get a single row with a single column. In the Advanced tab of the Flat File Connection Manager, set the DataType to `Unicode text stream`.

You now have the raw text as an NTEXT field. If you import this into an NVARCHAR(MAX) field in a db table, you'll be able to use SQL's xml processing, which I believe is what you're trying to achieve.